# VBA XMLHTTP query returning 403 error

Tags: json, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am currently attempting to retrieve a json string using XMLHTTP in VBA from the website url detailed below. Loading the first url creates a session, which I retrieve from the HTML body. A call to the second url, using the session ID & other request headers visible from develop tools results in a 403 error. I have tried multiple combinations of headers with no effect. For deployment purposes a VBA solution is required. Any input/ideas would be much appreciated.

```
Sub test()

Dim wbk_TB As Workbook
Dim var_array As Variant

Dim url As String
Dim data As Variant
Dim XMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set wbk_TB = ThisWorkbook
Set XMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
url = "http://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/germany/production/availability/non-usability"
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False

XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
XMLHTTP.send

data = XMLHTTP.responseText

Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText

Name = "session=" & HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("session").Item(0).Value

url = "http://www.eex-transparency.com/dsp/tem-12?country=de&limit=50&offset=50"

XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, True
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host", "www.eex-transparency.com"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Proxy-Connection", "keep-alive"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/germany/production/availability/non-usability"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", Name

XMLHTTP.send

While XMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

data = XMLHTTP.responseText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttp object does not allow unsafe header settings including spoofed referer header. Details are available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218525/set-referer-for-xml-http-request)

As the referer header is missing in the request, a status 403 is returned. In case you need to get the JSON from VBA, you would need to use an Internet Explorer object and browse to the [first URL](http://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/germany/production/availability/non-usability) and once that is loaded, need to navigate to the [Second URL](http://www.eex-transparency.com/dsp/tem-12?country=de&limit=50&offset=50) by programatically emulating a click on the correct link and then try to capture the data.